# Javascript multi-selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following functionality (see link: http://jsfiddle.net/eUDRV/3/) and instead of appending the selected values back to the original list, I'd like to return them to the spot that they were previously in. My values are in alphabetical order. I know that I need to index the spot of each value but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<section class="container">
<div>
    <select id="leftValues" size="5" multiple></select>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnLeft" value="&lt;&lt;" />
    <input type="button" id="btnRight" value="&gt;&gt;" />
</div>
<div>
    <select id="rightValues" size="4" multiple>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtRight" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$("#btnLeft").click(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
    $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);
});

$("#btnRight").click(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
    $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
});

$("#rightValues").change(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
    $("#txtRight").val(selectedItem.text());
});
```

CSS code:

```
SELECT, INPUT[type="text"] {
    width: 160px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
SECTION {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow: auto;
}
SECTION > DIV {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px;
}
SECTION > DIV + DIV {
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign each option within your select a value attribute that corresponds to the text and then in your code:

```
$("#btnLeft").click(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
    $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);
});
```

You could have it look up the value of the selected item, compare it with anything in the list and place it in the appropriate index in that list and do the same for the code which moves it back into the right hand list.

You could also strip the innerHTML value of the option instead if you didn't want to add the value attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. I think I'm going to go with the innerHTML option.